# Cant install xampp (Syntax error : Unterminated quoted string)

Tags: 12.04, xampp

Sorry for my english 
i did those steps

1) Dowmload de file :

```
xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

2) Open terminal...

```
   JonasJhy@Ububtu:~/Downloads$
```

3) Write this

```
   JonasJhy@Ububtu:~/Downloads$ chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

4) And write this

```
   JonasJhy@Ububtu:~/Downloads$ sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

...and then the computer show me this

```
./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run: 2: ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run: Syntax error : Unterminated quoted string
```

whats the problem,

Can you help me

Comment: please list the output of the command `uname -m`

Comment: Sounds like a source code bug to me. Write to the xampp guys. They have been quick to fix bugs i have found in the past. unterminated quote is probably the exact problem in the .run source.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful for installing xampp on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop..........

Comment: I too had the same problem You probably have a 32 bit operating system. The file xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run is for 64 bit OS. Try using the other version. Worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using the ppa

Add the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/xampp
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install XAMPP:

```
sudo apt-get install xampp
```