# Cannot install xampp in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, xampp

I was trying to install xampp into my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I got guidance from this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9P0rjonfPo) to do that. But it wasn't working well for me. I got stuck at the middle. Help me get out of it. These were the steps followed by me to get it.

I went  [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and downloaded xampp version 1.8.3 for linux. And I proceeded with the following terminal messages.

[image: Terminal Image]

I would be highly grateful if I could install xampp in the same way as my video teaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description and details about .run files are disscused in here [What are .run files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13415/what-are-run-files) the problem in your case is that you should run following commands

`chmod 755  xampp.run[or any of your package name]`

`sudo ./xampp.run`
not

`chmod 777 -R xampp.run`

`./xampp.run`

see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/678386/syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string-running-run-file) for more info

you can download your package from one more method

add ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/xampp`

update

`sudo apt-get update`

install xampp

`sudo apt-get install xampp`

check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414740/cant-install-xampp-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string) link for more help

also you should check if you have downloaded a correct file or not according to your hardware configuration like for 64-bit os you have downloaded x64 or i386 file

Comment: after which command are you getting error

Comment: what are you doing don't use (``) use the command except these quotes or whatever they are

Comment: use ';' after your command

Comment: use full path in the command line for xampp where you downloaded it like /downloads/xampp.run

Comment: yeah it is nessesary check the links for details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15844/discussion-between-creator-and-ramvignesh).